# SQLite ничего не возвращает

Tags: python, sql, sqlite3

У меня проблема. SQLite ничего не возвращает. Хотя к базе подключен. И в базе данных точно есть такой id. При запуске возвращает None. Курсор тоже подключен.

```
def Select(idd: str):
    conn= _connect()
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""SELECT id FROM users WHERE coin = ?""",[int(idd)])
    print(cursor.fetchall())
    return cursor.fetchone()
```

```
def _connect():
    global _conn
    if _conn is None:
        _conn = sqlite3.connect('data_base.db' )
    return _conn
```

Comment: Я print для проверки проверки написал

Answer (score 1):

Причина в том что исспользуется fetchall после которого курсор пуст, то есть применение fetchone после fetchall всегда вернёт none.

Comment: до printa не работал

Comment: @RAkim то есть принт выводин none?

Comment: оно до принта не работал

Comment: @RAkim выдаёт ошибку или возвращает None?

Comment: Без ошибки просто нечего не возвращает без принта

Comment: А должно id, не работает

Comment: @RAkim что выводит принт? `print('|',cursor.fetchall(),'|')

Comment: print(cursor.fetchall() ) возвращает None

Comment: @RAkim явный запрос вида `cursor.execute("SELECT id FROM users WHERE coin = 123;")` что выводит в принте?

Comment: Возвращает none но в базе такой есть

Comment: id в базе идёт как индекс или как строка? commit базы был сделан? файл бд точно тот же? через программы типа sqlitestudio что возвращается?

Comment: идет через index

Comment: commit сделан файл тот же через sqlitestudio все правильно

Answer (score 0):

Есть буфер данных после выполнения запроса, который опустошается при обращении к нему

И `fetchall` считает полностью и вернет в виде списка, а если данных нет, то вернется пустой список.
А `fetchone` считает одну запись, а если данных нет, то вернет `None`.

Подготовил пример данных:

```
import sqlite3

connect = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

connect.executescript('''\
CREATE TABLE Test (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    value TEXT
);

INSERT INTO Test (name, value) VALUES ('One', '1');
INSERT INTO Test (name, value) VALUES ('Two', '1');
INSERT INTO Test (name, value) VALUES ('Three', '2');
''')
```

Выборки из `fetchall` + `fetchone`, как видно `fetchall` вычитал всё, поэтому `fetchone` вернул `None`:

```
cursor = connect.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from Test where value = ?', ['1'])
print(cursor.fetchall())  # [(1, 'One', '1'), (2, 'Two', '1')]
print(cursor.fetchone())  # None
```

Выборки из `fetchone` + `fetchall`, как видно `fetchone` вернул первую запись, а `fetchall` оставшиеся:

```
cursor.execute('select * from Test where value = ?', ['1'])
print(cursor.fetchone())  # (1, 'One', '1')
print(cursor.fetchall())  # [(2, 'Two', '1')]
```

Выборки из `fetchall` + `fetchall`, как видно `fetchall` вычитал всё, поэтому следующий `fetchall` вернул пустой список:

```
cursor.execute('select * from Test where value = ?', ['1'])
print(cursor.fetchall())  # [(1, 'One', '1'), (2, 'Two', '1')]
print(cursor.fetchall())  # []
```

Поэтому, ваш пример с `fetchall` и последующим `fetchone` всегда из функции будет `None` возвращать.
А если же у вас и `fetchall` ничего не возвращает (возвращает пустой список), значит в таблице нет данных по текущему запросу

Comment: простите но до принта оно возвращал none и я проверял в базе такой айди есть

Comment: Меня немного смущает, что в условии у вас `coin`, а то, что в фильтр передается похоже на `id`: `SELECT id FROM users WHERE coin = ?""",[int(idd)]` :) Тут нет опечатки?

Comment: да есть место coin  должно стоят id